# Azure AD Owin with Iframe solution

Tags: iframe, asp.net-mvc-5, owin, azure-active-directory

I have a app which is setup to use Owin and Azure AD.  It works well, but I have now a requirement to run inside an iframe as part of a third party solution.

This is OK apart from the security.  https://login.microsoftonline.com does not allow running inside an iframe.  My controller will check if the user is authenticated and if not, call 'HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(..............'

On research it looks unlikely that I can do anything inside the frame.  Is my only option to create a sign-in page, which redirects to the client app which includes the iframe?  If this expires, the iframe then currently displays an error stating the content cannot be displayed in a frame, this is not very elegant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AAD does not permit framing of pages where credentials are entered. This requirements stems from a need to prevent click jacking style attacks. See: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking. Instead, you can do a full frame authentication initially and then do I frame authentication with prompt=none to refresh the ticket. Prompt=none tells AAD that it is not permitted to stop and ask for credentials, so this flow will always work in an iframe.

Comment: Thanks Will, have you got an example of prompt parameter and can't find any having just searched on it.  I use HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge in the controller, is there an extention or do I have to redirect to a hand crafted URL?

Comment: One of the notifications fires on redirect to IdP. You should be able to set context.ProtocolMessage.Prompt = none there. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.openidconnect.openidconnectauthenticationnotifications.redirecttoidentityprovider(v=vs.113).aspx#P:Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications.RedirectToIdentityProvider

Comment: @SteveNewton  What do you mean for "full-frame authentication"?

Comment: For what it's worth, I could not get this working. Even with `prompt=none`, Chrome gives me "Refused to display <URL> in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'."

Comment: Hi, @RobSiklos. Were you able to solve that problem?
I am also having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum to the accepted answer, I was able to work around the issue by ensuring that the iframe URL's casing matched exactly what I'd provided in my app registration in Azure AD. E.g. if Azure AD has https://mydomain/My-App/ as one of my reply URLs then ensure that the iframe URL is spelled exactly the same way. I initially had my iframe URL as https://mydomain/my-app/my-page and was encountering the same issue described above till I changed the casing to https://mydomain/My-App/my-page.